# How to write test cases for variable arguments in a method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to write unit test for the below class. 
The methods are called using variable arguments.Can any one help me how to write test cases for variable arguments methods?

```
  class WCfg  {

  private void setAddr(MCfg mCfg, String... arg)
             throws Exception {
    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new Exception("Invalid IP address.", e);
    }
  }

  public String process(String... arg) throws Exception {
    MCfg mCfg = new MCfg();

    try {      

      setAddr(mCfg, arg);

     } catch (Exception e) {
       return "Wrong argument format.";
     }

     mCfg.write();

    return "success";
  }
}
```

Test code:

```
   import org.junit.Test;

   public class MCfgTest {

   @Test
    public void Success() throws Exception {
      WCfg wmc = new WCfg();
      wmc.process(String... arg);
    }
 }
```

Comment: To test a method you need to call it and check the result. You can call a method with variable arguments just like any other method. Could you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: Here I want to write unit test some thing like below. how to populate the "arg" variable before triggering the "process" function.



Test code:

**bold**

       import org.junit.Test;

        public class WriteMapCfgTest {

       @Test
        public void processSuccess() throws Exception {
        WriteMapCfg wmc = new WriteMapCfg();
        wmc.process(String... arg);
      }
    }

Answer (score 3):

Simple; you want to test all possible options how "varargs" could be used:

```
WriteMapCfg underTest = ... 

@Test
public void testProcessWithNoArgs() {
  underTest.process();

@Test
public void testProcessWithNullArray() {
  underTest.process((String []) null);
  ...

@Test
public void testProcessWithNullString() {
  underTest.process((String) null);
  ...

@Test
public void testProcessWithOneString() {
  underTest.process("whatever");
  ...

@Test
public void testProcessWithMultipleStrings() {
  underTest.process("whatever", "whocares");
  ...
```

The point is: those 5 cases are possible; and you need at least one testcase for each of that.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try this.

Comment: `testProcessWithNoArgs` is another possible testcase.